# how I can evaluation the depth map result?

Tags: evaluation, depth

Code section 1

```
!mkdir -p inputs
!mkdir -p outputs_midas
!mkdir -p outputs_leres
```

Code section 2

Clone git repo

```
!git clone https://github.com/compphoto/BoostingMonocularDepth.git

!wget https://sfu.ca/~yagiz/CVPR21/latest_net_G.pth
#!gdown https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1cU2y-kMbt0Sf00Ns4CN2oO9qPJ8BensP&export=download

# Downloading merge model weights
!mkdir -p /content/BoostingMonocularDepth/pix2pix/checkpoints/mergemodel/
!mv latest_net_G.pth /content/BoostingMonocularDepth/pix2pix/checkpoints/mergemodel/

# Downloading Midas weights
!wget https://github.com/AlexeyAB/MiDaS/releases/download/midas_dpt/midas_v21-f6b98070.pt
!mv midas_v21-f6b98070.pt /content/BoostingMonocularDepth/midas/model.pt

# # Downloading LeRes weights
!wget https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/s/lTIJF4vrvHCAI31/download
!mv download /content/BoostingMonocularDepth/res101.pth
```

Code section 3

```
%cd BoostingMonocularDepth/
```

Running the method using LeRes

```
!python run.py --Final --data_dir /content/inputs --output_dir  /content/outputs_leres/ --depthNet 2
```

I applies this code to ceate depth map and this is my result I need way evalute the result
ther is part in github to evalution but I dont know how can I running this part

```
./evaluation/evaluatedataset.m
```

code link:
!git clone https://github.com/compphoto/BoostingMonocularDepth.git

and this is the image and the rusult
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CVRA.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqLm4.jpg)